# How can I convert DataTable in C# to a DataFrame using RdotNet

Tags: datatable, dataframe

I am writing a program in c# and using RdotNet to connect C# to R. I convert the value from dataGridView to DataTable in order to pass the value to another class. Then, I want to convert this DataTable into Dataframe using RdotNet.
Is it possible to convert DataTable or string[,] generated from dataGridView in C# to a DataFrame using R.Net? How can I do this?

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @Artiga I don't get any solution to convert DataTable to DataFrame. So, in my case, I convert the DataTable into double[], then convert it into NumericVector type. It's a long way thought.

Comment: For data access between R, .NET and C#, you need to see https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 0):

I just answered the question [Creating a Data.Frame using R.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33335113/2752565), which is similar to what you are asking. I missed this present question when it was first asked.

Note that the latest documentation is now hosted at http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet, not the codeplex site.