# Creating a Data.Frame using R.NET

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I'm using the R.NET project in C# to call R functions. Is there a way to create a DataFrame in C#? I see there is a DataFrame type here: https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/documentation

Currently I can create a data.frame in R by manipulating my data (integer values) into a series of strings and then using R.NET's evaluate command, but is there a way where I can push my data (integer values) to R without having to go through a string conversion process?

For example (and my ultimate question is), is there a way to create a DataFrame in C# using native integer values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems it is possible: [look at that](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Handling%20DataFrames&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: But when looking [at this](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/R.NET/RDotNet/DataFrame) it seems there is no SetRow() method

Answer (score 1):

The `REngine` object has a method `CreateDataFrame`, and this is the preferred way to create data frames.

You'll find example usage [in the R.NET unit tests](https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet/blob/master/RDotNet.Tests/DataFrameTest.cs).

Another example can be found in [an optimisation log extraction utility](https://github.com/jmp75/metaheuristics/blob/devel/src/CSIRO.Metaheuristics.R/LogHelper.cs)

Comment: Thanks, @j-m. After further research, this seems to be the only way to do it through a specifically defined R.NET method. However, I found that I was able to achieve faster results by simply calling the eval method on the R.net engine and using syntax as one would use in R. So a simple example would be: myREngine.eval ("myDataframe <- data.frame (col1=c(1,2,3), col2=c(4,5,6), col3=c(7,8,9)"); ... I created a method to create the eval string given a C# DataFrame object, which, altogether, works faster than the CreateDataFrame method.