# how can I create Named List Members object in R.net?

Tags: r.net

How can I create "Named List Members" in R.NET? The R code looks like this:

```
odpar <- list(mean = c(-1.5, 0, 1.5), var = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.8))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
var engine = this.Engine;
var list = new GenericVector(engine, 2);
// odpar <- list(mean = c(-1.5, 0, 1.5), var = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.8)) 
list[0] = engine.CreateNumericVector(new[] { -1.5, 0, 1.5 });
list[1] = engine.CreateNumericVector(new[] { 0.5, 0.6, 0.8 });
list.SetNames("mean", "var");
engine.SetSymbol("TestListSetNames", list);
var listNames = engine.Evaluate("names(TestListSetNames)").AsCharacter().ToArray();
Assert.AreEqual("mean", listNames[0]);
Assert.AreEqual("var", listNames[1]);
```

Or, if your list can be created as a data frame (which is closely related to lists), you can follow the examples provided in links at [this post, creating-a-data-frame-using-r-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288861/creating-a-data-frame-using-r-net)